# Rename files in a folder with extensions

Tags: windows, file, powershell, rename, command-prompt

I have a folder full of .html files that i am trying to rename, but I want to keep the existing name as part of the new name, and I'm having trouble because of the new filename format. I need them to go from:

filename.html

to

company.filename.pat.html

The result is the existing filename needs to be sandwiched in the middle of some periods, and thats throwing me foe a loop. Anyone have suggestions on how to archive this? Command line or powershell both work.

the "company" and "pat" parts will be the same for all files, so i dont need to account for any variations there, thankfully.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try anything? Post your code and the specific problem you are facing

Comment: Sorry, yes, i tried 
ren *.html company.*.pat.hml - it renamed only one file, and didnt carry over the current name, it was just called company.html.pat.html  
I know i need to pass the name into the result as a variable, i just cant find the right syntax. Spent about half an hour googling it so far.

Comment: sorry, asterisks didnt show, the command i used was:
ren STAR.html company.STAR.pat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell

```
cd c:\yourdir\withfiles\
ls | % { ren $_.Name ( "company." + $_.BaseName + ".pat" + $_.Extension) }
```